# Need help figured out how to load nested list from yml in spring boot java app

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I have a yaml file setup like this:

```
system:
  locators:
  - first.com
    - 103
    - 105
  - second.com
    - 105
```

I want to load this as `@autowired` configuration that looks something like this:

```
@Autowired
List<Locator> locators;
```

I'm thinking that the Locator class would look something like this:

```
class Locator {
    String name;
    List<String> ports;
}
```

But I'm not sure how to put this all together. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly, I believe your yaml file structure is invalid. In your Locator class you have given names to the fields - you should do the same in your yaml file. In the end it should look like this:

```
system:
  locators:
  - name: first.com
    ports:
      - 103
      - 105
  - name: second.com
    ports:
      - 105
```

Secondly, you can leverage Spring Boot's rather advanced properties-to-bean auto mapping. As in every Spring Boot app, you need to annotate your main class with  @SpringBootApplication. Then, you can create a class representing your properties structure:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "system")
public class SystemProperties {

    private List<Locator> locators;

    public List<Locator> getLocators() {
        return locators;
    }

    public void setLocators(List<Locator> locators) {
        this.locators = locators;
    }

    public static class Locator {
        private String name;
        private List<String> ports;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public List<String> getPorts() {
            return ports;
        }

        public void setPorts(List<String> ports) {
            this.ports = ports;
        }

    }

}
```

Notice the @ConfigurationProperties annotation that defines the prefix which is the root of this classe's mapped configuration. It can of course be any node in a yaml tree of properties, not necessarily the main level as in your case.

For further reading I would suggest this [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2013/10/30/empowering-your-apps-with-spring-boot-s-property-support) and the [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html) as there are more ppowerful abilities when it comes to property bean mapping.

Comment: Does this work in Spring MVC ? I tried but not working :(

Comment: Don't forget to copy getters and setters when testing this example or use @@Getter @@Setter annotations from Lombok. If you skip this part (as I did) SB won't be able to bind the configuration values

Answer (score 0):

Assume the following config class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {


    List<Users> users;
}
```

the according application.yml entry would look like this:

```
app.users:
  -
    name: "name1"
    password: "password1"
  -
    name: "name2"
    password: "password2"
  -
    name: "name3"
    password: "password3"
```