# Yaml properties not loaded in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, java-17

I would like to use application.yml instead of application.properties

I followed: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

I am using:

- SpringBoot 2.6.2
- Java 17
- Gradle 7.3.2

My MCVE:
https://github.com/OldEngineer1911/demo1

The issue is: Properties are not loaded. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution from "@Panagiotis Bougiokos" is partially correct:

```
Products products = app.getBean(Products.class); <---Retrieve the Proxy instance from Spring Context
```

Is necessary, but the rest is optional (it is possible to write List in yml both ways). The solution was to fix yml file with nested products:

```
products:
  products:
    - 'first'
    - 'second'
```

And also add setter for products:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="products")
public class Products {
    private List<String> products;

    public List<String> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<String> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
}
```

This is a working solution (everyone can check Github mentioned in the question). Anyway, it still can be improved - don't know why do I need nested products.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following code

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo1Application.class, args);
        Products products = new Products();  <---------------------------------ERROR!!!
        List<String> productsFromApplicationYml = products.getProducts();

        System.out.println(productsFromApplicationYml.size()); // I would like to see 2
        products.getProducts().forEach(System.out::println); // I would like to see "first" and "second"
    }



@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="products")
public class Products {
    private final List<String> products = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
}
```

The error is in the line  `Products products = new Products();` of your main method. You don't retrieve the bean from Spring context but you create it by yourself in the JVM. Therefore it is as you created it empty.

Read more to understand how Spring uses proxies for your spring beans and not the actual classes that you write.

What you need is the following

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ApplicationContext app = SpringApplication.run(Demo1Application.class, args)

  Products products = app.getBean(Products.class); <---Retrieve the Proxy instance from Spring Context

  List<String> productsFromApplicationYml = products.getProducts();
  System.out.println(productsFromApplicationYml.size())
```

**Edit:**

You have also false configured your `application.yml` file.

```
products:
  - first
  - second
```

The symbol `-` is used for array of complex objects which spring will try to serialize from `application.yml`. Check what I mean in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33821690/7237884)

Considering that you don't have a list of custom objects but a primitive `List<String>` your `application.yml` should be in the following form

```
products: first,second
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried (as can be seen here: https://github.com/OldEngineer1911/demo1/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/demo/Demo1Application.java ) to apply the proposed solution, but it does not change the output... Variable from property file is not displayed.

Comment: @OldEngineer check updated answer, I have found the error

Comment: Thanks for the update! But it still does not work. I applied a second fix and the property is still not loaded.

Comment: @OldEngineer Try doing another change in `Products.class` from `private List<String> products = new ArrayList<>();`` change it into `private List<String> products;` so that spring does the initialization and not you manually

Comment: I am getting: NPE: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.size()" because "productsFromApplicationYml" is null. It looks like spring does not initialize it. Don't know why, it should be according to docs (mentioned above).

Comment: @OldEngineer try also under `@SpringBootApplication` to include also `@EnableConfigurationProperties(Products.class)`

Comment: NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.demo.Products' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: products,products-com.example.demo.Products. - I already tried to play with annotations without success.